# How to select cell range dynamically in sumproduct in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use Sumproduct dynamically on a sheet that will be updated regularly.

My motive is to not manually select the columns ( i.e. not to use the shift key and down key to select the range A2:A6 as seen in the attached snapshot)

I want to have the formula "=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A6="TX"))" pick up the A2:A6 dynamically since my data in worksheet say A is everchanging. So that when the data has grown to A8, it can be somehow picked up dynamically than manually using the keys.

Can this be done? Please let me know if my question is not clear.

[Screenshot of my xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmQVj.png)

Regards
SM

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could define the range dynamically. However, given your current formula, I see no reason why you should not switch to `COUNTIF` here, i.e.:

`=COUNTIF(A:A,"TX")`

a function for which the use of entire column referencing (`A:A` here) has no detriment to performance (which is not at all the case with `SUMPRODUCT`).

Regards

Comment: Thank you XOR LX, it seems it can serve my purpose. The following is the formula I am using. =SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($'FQ Incidents'.$F$3:$F$32)=C$2);--(YEAR($'FQ Incidents'.$F$3:$F$32)=2016);--(($'FQ Incidents'.$D$3:$D$32=$A$8))). So inorder to have dynamic selection, can i just replace the SUMPRODUCT with COUNTIF ?

Comment: Your references look wrong here. Why does 'FQ Incidents' have a dollar-sign ($) before it? And why a period (.) after it? And also no exclamation marks (!) anywhere? Surely this syntax will be rejected by Excel, no matter which version you are using? I would've thought: SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH('FQ Incidents'!$F$3:$F$32)=C$2);--(YEAR('FQ Incidents'!$F$3:$F$32)=2016);--(('FQ Incidents'!$D$3:$D$32=$A$8))) would be correct.

Comment: XOR LX, Workseet 1 contains the columns F and D etc which I use. And I am using worksheet 2 for Summary and this is where I am using the formula referring the worksheet 1. So I am not seeing any errors. Possibly maybe because I am using open office..(i guess). Anyways can I use something like $F:$F for the dynamic selection of column?

Comment: Using entire column references within SUMPRODUCT would not at all be a good idea. Try: =COUNTIFS('FQ Incidents'!$F:$F,">="&DATE(2016,C$2,1),'FQ Incidents'!$F:$F,"<"&DATE(2016,C$2+1,1),'FQ Incidents'!$D:$D,$A$8), which is correct for Excel, though I have no idea of how you arrive at the syntax you give, and would not know how to 'translate' the above for you if it doesn't work in Open Office.

Answer (score 0):

Shitty recommendations guy, here.

Can you insert a new line above all in your sheet? You could put it really wherever you want and you can even hide it, the first line just works for me.

If you can, just make it an "count.values" function on the entire column with an appropriated subtraction to adjust the count to the right length of your data. E.g. Removing this auxiliary cell value plus a header would be "=count.values(A:A)-2".

Later, on your VBA, you could retrieve this value to a variable and concatenate it to your main function. Lets say you made the auxiliary on cell A1 (coordinates 1, 1)

`Dim auxLine As Integer
auxLine = cells(1, 1).value
whatever.formular1c1 = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A" & auxLine & ="TX"))"`